# How to load an Ajax loaded array of JSON from Django/Python view into DataTable

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, datatable

I am new developer and this is my first professional project and first in Django too.
I am trying to load data I fetched from my models.py in my view.py to a DataTable.
Here is my code.

**Here is my views.py**

```
def recordingDataTable(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
        vicidial_agent_log = VicidialAgentLog.objects.filter(event_time__gte='2021-04-16 16:00:00').values('user', 'server_ip')
        structure = json.dumps(list(vicidial_agent_log), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        
        return JsonResponse(structure, status = 200, safe=False)
    
    return JsonResponse({}, status = 400)
```

**Here is the JSON that gets returned**

```
"[{\"user\": \"8045\", \"server_ip\": \"168.119.48.158\"}, {\"user\": \"8047\", \"server_ip\": \"168.119.48.158\"},]"
```

**Here is my Template**

```
<table id="recording_datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Server IP</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    
    </tbody>
    
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Server IP</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>
```

**Finally, here is my script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        'url': "{% url 'recordings:recordingDataTable' %}",
        'method': "GET",
        'dataType': "JSON",
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        
    }).done( function(data) {
        alert(data);
        
        $('#recording_datatable').DataTable({
            data: data,
            dataSrc: "",
            columns: [
                { data: "user" },
                { data: "server_ip" },
            ]
                
        });

    })
});
```

Whenever I run my code, I receive the following error: 
**DataTables warning: table id=recording_datatable - Requested unknown parameter 'user' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error.**
I have implemented a DataTable before already from PHP and seem to be doing everything right. I just don't know why it isn't working. I have visited almost every document on here, Stackoverflow and Datatables.net and for some reason no implementation seem to be working.

I know it will turn out to be a simple error but this problem has taken better part of my 3 days. Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your JavaScript code looks OK. But your JSON is not actually JSON - it's a string representation of JSON (and it's incomplete - but perhaps it is just an edited version for the question). Why are you using `json.dumps`? You should be passing an array of objects to JsonResponse, `[ {"user": "Joe" }, { "user": "Jane" } ]` - not passing a string.

Comment: Oh man! I legit just did this and it feels so silly. Yes, it isn't JSON. I just converted it in JSON like this, and it worked. ```const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);```. 
I used json.dumps() because of a solution I found online. I guess my Python or web development needs to be sharpen a lot. Thanks man for your help.
Lastly, can you help me why my ```return JsonResponse(structure, status = 200, safe=False)``` is not returning JSON to my template?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution thanks to help from @andrewjames. I was passing a string instead of JSON response. Rookie mistake maybe.

I was using json.dumps() in my views.py file because I wanted to serialize the object before passing it to jsonResponse() but that was wrong implementation.
First I changed the string to JSON in template by `const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);` and my data populated the datatable.
Once I realized my mistake, I eventually edited my views.py file to send jsonResponse() and I did it in the following way.

```
def recordingDataTable(request):

    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
        vicidial_agent_log = VicidialAgentLog.objects.filter(event_time__gte='2021-04-16 16:00:00').values('user', 'server_ip')
        return JsonResponse(list(vicidial_agent_log), status = 200, safe=False)
    return JsonResponse({}, status = 400)
```